# When reading file through stdin input(), it's loading just 1 line

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, stdin

When I run this code in cmd, through command: `py file.py textfile.txt`,
it reads just the first line of the textfile.txt for some reason, and I do not understand why ...

```
input_numbers = []
final_numbers_array = []

input_file = input()
print (input_file)
input_numbers = input_file.split(" ")

for x in range(len(input_numbers)):
    if(input_numbers[x]!=""):
        final_numbers_array.append(int(input_numbers[x]))

    elif(input_numbers[x]!="\n"):
         final_numbers_array.append(int(input_numbers[x]))

    elif(input_numbers[x]!="\t"):
         final_numbers_array.append(int(input_numbers[x]))

    else:
        pass
            
print(final_numbers_array)
```

Comment: You are working with the file name, not with the file contents.

Comment: It actually reads the first line, so i dont think so, it reads the first line and print it, but nothing else.

Comment: But there is no `open` in your code, how can it read from file?

Comment: I am a programming pepega, but i was told, that by inputing it, it inputs the file as a string  with the content of the file, when u write call it like that.

Comment: No, what you describe doesn't even remotely match how things work. You have multiple fundamental misunderstandings and need to follow a tutorial rather than trying to get help on Stack Overflow. This is beyond the scope of a single question here, and the individual questions that could be asked have all been repeatedly asked before (and are also covered by existing tutorials and documentation).